# CSS Styling fill space left in the left of the element and the right of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

imagine an element, which is centered in its container, has its width, but don't know the exact width, something like text and i want the left space and right space to be same and colored, something like this:

----------------- Test This -----------------

```css
#left {
  background-color: red;
}
#middle {
  width: 200px;
  /* it might be different */
}
#right {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Comment: actually there are many techniques to make any element center... as of now see how to use flex css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .container{
       display:flex;
    }
     .main-body{
       flex:1 1 auto;
    }
    #left{
        background-color: red;
   }
   #middle{
        width: 200px;
       text-align:center;
  }
    #right{
        background-color: red;
    }
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main-body" id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle">Hello</div>
    <div  class="main-body" id="right"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved using `display: flex`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
#middle {
  /* it might be different */
}
#right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="middle">Some text</div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="middle">Some long text can go here!</div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: flexbox is a CSS3 property. Check browser compatibility here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Answer (score 0):

Split into equal spaces using bootstrap and then fill color

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 fill-color"> h</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">h</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 fill-color">h</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.fill-color {
   background: red;
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scsiva1991/mky1q4a0/)

Answer (score 0):

Surround your div by another div "container" , now you don't need left and right divs.. 
     
        Your Text here, Div is surrounded by container div
    
    
        #container {
            background-color: red;
        }

```
    #middle {
        font-size: 30px;
        width: 80%;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: white;
    }


</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add margin attribute to both left and right div of yours.Fix the width of left and right div.Try this , i guess it will sort out your problem